# Calculate and store cell title and description for a NSManagedObject in use within a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I have those two methods that provide title and a description for cell, declared in a protocol.

```
@protocol TableCellProtocol <NSObject>

@optional
@property(readonly,nonatomic,strong) NSString *titleForCell;
@property(readonly,nonatomic,strong) NSString *descriptionForCell;

@end
```

I have a NSManagedObject implementing that protocol and providing relevant methods:

```
-(NSString*)titleForCell {
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",self.myVar1,self.myVar2];
}

-(NSString*)descriptionForCell {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",self.myVar3,self.myVar4];
}
```

where `self.myVar<n>` are CoreData attributes.

This protocol is meant to be used in a UITableViewCell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id<TableCellProtocol> obj = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableCell"];
    cell.cellTitle.text=obj.titleForCell;
    cell.cellDescr.text=obj.descriptionForCell;

    return cell;
}
```

Although I am not having memory leak or allocation problems, I found this not really elegant, and quite poor for performance reason, because every time the cell is displayed a new NSString is created.

Also, the relevant attributes, may change during application lifecycle, so in case of storing title and description somewhere, I am in need to refresh them when needed.

I am using ARC in my project.

Comment: The better approach would be to create some transient properties for the object and then use create the dependent values in custom getter method. This will preserve the value once it is created and it is the recommended one.

Comment: In this case, how can I efficiently refresh title and desc when related property change ?

Comment: well, you could use willTurnInfoFault/didTurnIntoFault method to clear the transient attributes and that should do it.

Comment: But the object is not always faulted.

Comment: What do you mean by not always faulted. If you think that the property change and you save the context then those methods will surely be called.

Comment: If you are still using the object, for example in a UITableView as it is my case, the object is not faulted. Unless it is turned into fault by myself.

Comment: Well in that case, just refresh the same object from the context using refreshObject:mergeContext: Hope this helps.

Comment: A few time has passed, I wanted to say that I ended up implementing the transient attribute mechanism you mentioned. If you want to write it down as an answer I can mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to your comment above, I will post the use of transient attribute to store the custom attribute in NSManagedObject subclass. This approach is very efficient in terms of memory as the managed object context hold onto the object until the context is reset and also if some changes occur it automatically changes the attributes accordingly. In your case, you had to create the string each time you created or reused a cell. But, now since we cache the object, once the transient attribute is created, it is always there and it does not have any memory overhead. So it should be much faster.

You could implement the transient attribute as follows:

```
@implementation SomeManagedObject

   + (NSSet*)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key{
     if([key isEqualToString:@"cellTitle"]){
      return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"myVar1", @"myVar2", nil];
    }else if([key isEqualToString: @"cellDescription"]){
      return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"myVar3", @"myVar4", nil];
    }
     return [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];
   } 

  // You could either override the getter for the transient attribute like this

  - (NSString*)cellTitle{
   if(!_cellTitle){
    [sell willChangeValueForKey: @"cellTitle"]; 
     _cellTitle =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",self.myVar1,self.myVar2];
    [self didChangeValueForKey: @"cellTitle"];
   }
   return _cellTitle;
  }

  // You could also override the awakeFromFetch method to create the transient attribute as

 - (void)awakeFromFetch{
    [sell willChangeValueForKey: @"cellTitle"]; 
     _cellTitle =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",self.myVar1,self.myVar2];
    [self didChangeValueForKey: @"cellTitle"];  
    [super awakeFromFetch];
}

 // Also use the willTurnIntoFault/didTurnIntoFault method as

 - (void)didTurnIntoFault{
     [super didTurnIntoFault];
     [sell willChangeValueForKey: @"cellTitle"]; 
     _cellTitle =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",self.myVar1,self.myVar2];
    [self didChangeValueForKey: @"cellTitle"];  
 }

@end
```

I hope that helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Instead of declaring two properties and defining their getter methods, you could define two methods that return String. And use this to set the title and description for your tableViewCell.

```
@protocol TableCellProtocol <NSObject>

@optional
-(NSString *) getTitleForCell;
-(NSString *) getDescriptionForCell;

@end




-(NSString*)getTitleForCell {
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",self.myVar1,self.myVar2];
}

-(NSString*)getDescriptionForCell {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",self.myVar3,self.myVar4];
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.Thanks.

Comment: It's the same I am doing now, I am not storing title and desc. What I would like to avoid is creating a new NSString each time.

Comment: you mean, if you store the values, you have to refresh them when the table reloads ?
I am not able to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to reuse the cells in the tableview by checking if(cell==nil)

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

```
id<TableCellProtocol> obj = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
MyTableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableCell"];
```

if (cell == nil) {

```
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
cell.cellTitle.text=obj.titleForCell;
cell.cellDescr.text=obj.descriptionForCell;

return cell;
```

}

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` does not return `nil` if a nib object or class has been registered with `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. Also this seems to be unrelated to the question.